# From decimal ASCII number to int character

Tags: arduino, ascii

I want to read a file from an SD card that contains integers. The reading function returns decimal ASCII values between 48 to 57 which corresponds to the characters `'0'` to `'9'`. How can I save this character as an integer? This is the code I have now. If I run this code and read `'0'` from the file, access will be 48 and `c` as well.

```cpp
char c;
String chat_id;
int access;

int getaccess(String chat_id) {
  String a = "Gebruikers/" + chat_id + ".txt";
  if (!SD.exists(a.c_str())) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    myFile = SD.open("Gebruikers/" + chat_id + ".txt");
    if (myFile) {
      Serial.println("Getting the access number");
      access = myFile.read();
      myFile.close();
      Serial.println("done.");
      c = access + 0;
      return c;
    } else {
      Serial.println("error opening " + nummer + ".txt");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the Arduino stuff include `fscanf`?

Comment: No unfortunately not, I can only use the read() function

Comment: How about `Stream.parseInt`?

Comment: Yes, that worked. I did not know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are reading single digits, then just subtract 48 form the ASCII code and you'll get the number.

Most commonly written as:

```cpp
int oneDigitNumber = someAsciiCode - '0';
```